# Unsuccessful attempts to mask content for device simulation

Tags: overflow, border, masking

Completely our of my depth, trying to create a device frame for some scrollable content and mask the over flowing content:

https://dev.park-studio.com/test-phone-2/

Tried setting overflow to hidden on parent but no joy
Tried a border radius on .pw4-phone__content-wrap but no sucess

Am i sure i'm doing almost everything wrong in my attempts!

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. Links to external sites are not acceptable.